# Why my for loop's index getting increased while using grand dispatch

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I am using this method to show images on my images but when it comes into the dispatch method then index is getting increased.
Means when i is 1 it sets to 2.
Please let me know what the issue.

Thanks.

```
for var i = 0 ; i<featuredCards.count ; i++ {

    print("INDEXxxxxxxxxxxxx",i)
    if i >= self.cardFeatruedTitlesCollection.count {
        break
    }

    if photoModel.photoURL == featuredCards[i].cardPreviewImages[safe:0]?.photoURL {

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

        if let  path = photoModel.photoPath {

            if let image : UIImage = photoModel.getThumbnailPhotoWithPath(path) {

                if let imageView = self.cardFeaturedImagesCollection[safe:i] {
                    imageView.image = image
                }

            }
        }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got quite the pyramid of doom going on there. You should read up on `guard` statements and multiple `if let` bindings per statement

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing main queue in the loop which is not a good idea as dispatch block will be executed after completion of the loop iteration thats why it is getting incremented value.

You can resolve it by two ways

1. Use __block variable
2. Place your for loop inside the mainqueue block like below:

Try this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

    for var i = 0 ; i<featuredCards.count ; i++ {

        print("INDEXxxxxxxxxxxxx",i)
        if i >= self.cardFeatruedTitlesCollection.count {
            break
        }

        if photoModel.photoURL == featuredCards[i].cardPreviewImages[safe:0]?.photoURL {


            if let  path = photoModel.photoPath {

                if let image : UIImage = photoModel.getThumbnailPhotoWithPath(path) {

                    if let imageView = self.cardFeaturedImagesCollection[safe:i] {
                        imageView.image = image
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT : if you are using swift 3 then you should use following syntax :

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
    //Your For Loop
}
```

Comment: should i add __ for the variable i?

Answer (score 0):

When you queue a block of work onto the main queue using `dispatch_async`, control returns immediately to the call site (here, the loop), which then proceeds and increments `i` before the work you've queued executes (and reads the value of `i` you were expecting).

The value of `var i : Int` is shared state between the loop and the closure of code you're dispatching. This leads to a race condition: the loop may modify `i` before `i` is read by the queued work.

You can use a constant copy of `i` in your loop to reduce the amount of shared state.

```
let photoIndex = i

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
if let path = photoModel.photoPath {
    if let image : UIImage = photoModel.getThumbnailPhotoWithPath(path) {
        if let imageView = self.cardFeaturedImagesCollection[safe: photoIndex] {
            imageView.image = image
       }

    }
}
```